# What are the technical resources available to learn how to design beautiful web interfaces?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, photoshop

I know basic to intermediate level of CSS and Javascript / jQuery. However, I don't a thing about Photoshop. I want to learn how to design beautiful websites from scratch. This includes creating the background images and then using CSS and jQuery to provide a beautiful user interface / user experience. Are there good resources available to help take my design skills to the next level?

Comment: Your question is off-topic, IMHO.  However, you need two things to do graphical design from scratch... artistic talent and knowing how to use tools like Photoshop.

Comment: it's not a place to ask this type of question

Comment: Instead of downvoting, perhaps suggest a move to http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh ok didn't realize. Sorry about that! Will check out graphicdesign.stackexchange.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Improving as a designer**

I think there would be many very similar steps to becoming a good programmer:

- read foundational books on principles of art and design, not necessarily related to web design (i.e. learn about line, colour, form, balance of elements). Taking art classes (painting, sketching etc.) couldn't hurt.
- find a real project where you can take a web design soup to nuts, preferably for a real client, as negotiating with clients is half the art - web design is a people job as much as an artistic pursuit.
- read websites devoted to web design (and design in general), to stay current and get inspired.
- learn the vocabulary of modern web design (mockups, mood boards, design tiles etc.)
- practice constantly.
- find designs you like and try to create them yourself, research how the effects were achieved.
- meet other designers and share tips, tricks.
- be critical of your designs, ask for honest feedback. Take criticism in stride and be as honest as you can with yourself about where you need to improve.

**Improving as an interaction designer/front end developer**

Regarding CSS, a great book to take your skills from basic/intermediate to high-intermediate (and understanding the principles involved) is Andy Budd's [CSS Mastery](http://www.cssmastery.com/).

An equally great book on jQuery is [jQuery in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355). For JavaScript, Douglas Crockford's [JavaScript: the Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748).

For understanding interaction design, [Jared Spool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635027) is well-known.

Other great resources to improve as an all-around CSS/JS developer:

- [Smashing Magazine](http://smashingmagazine.com)
- [nettuts](http://nettuts.com/)
- [Six Revisions](http://sixrevisions.com)
- [SitePoint](http://sitepoint.com)
- [Many more listed here](http://sixrevisions.com/resources/websites_for_web_development/)

Answer (score -1):

```
http://www.w3schools.com/css/
http://sass-lang.com/
http://psd.tutsplus.com/
```

May also want to expand on pre-existing components. Im a big fan of EXTJS http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/ They have a community edition for open source projects

Comment: Any answer with a link to W3Schools is going to get my down-vote.  [See W3Fools](http://www.w3fools.com)